# C# Why does System.IO.File.Exists keep coming up false?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

> ```
> string profile = "\\" + txtProfileLoad.Text + ".txt";
> profile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + profile;
> ```

The variable profile is receiving the correct file path, but when I run it the File.Exists comes up false every time.

```
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(profile) == true)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader profileReader;
            profileReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(profile);

            do
            {
                profileLevel = profileLevel + profileReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
            } while (profileReader.Peek() != -1);

            loadName(profileLevel);

            wordBeingUsed.finalWord = loadedName;

            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid file name. Please try again.");
        }
```

There aren't any permissions stopping it from seeing the file.
Any help with this would be appreciated. It's been driving me crazy.

Comment: Instead of concatenation of unknown values it would be better to show something like `string profile = @"c:\users\aaa\Documents\foo.txt"`... Or at least explicit value instead of `txtProfileLoad.Text `.

Comment: I apologize for the unknown values. I have it set up to take the value in the text box. I know for a fact it receives it perfectly fine and that the file path turns out fine as well. The actual file path is: C:\\User\\USER\\Documents\\Saves.txt

Comment: GetFolderPath - on my machine - doesn't return a filename with double backslashes. How can it be "perfectly fine"? And why don't you use Path.Combine" which is meant for ... ummm ... combining paths?

Comment: I have very little knowledge with C# as I just started learning not too long ago. I didn't know about Path.Combine so I'll go ahead and look into it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: OP didn't specify from where he got his "knowledge" that the path is "perfectly fine". Might be from Debugger, Console.Print, Debug.Print, setting a label whatever. As far as I have experienced, most error occur, because one ASSUMES that something is "fine". And of course it shold be checked WHEN the path is/was fine.

Comment: @igrimpe - I've already figured that it was not nice comment... so I'll delete both. Anyway if you look at the code that constructs `profile` you'll notice that it can't have `\\` before file name because `GetFolderPath` does not return path with `\\`  - so it is unlikely OP is faking the path that bad (and even less likely to be incorrectly constructed via code).

Comment: For the record, the file path was from the debugger. Also, I created the file and placed it into that file path in order to simply test the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a pre-existing file that you are trying to read? Or is this a new file that you are hoping to create? What is the value inside `txtProfileLoad.Text`, issue most likely is within this property.

Run a sanity check:

```
var profile = "mytestfile.txt";
var myFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), profile);
File.WriteAllText(myFile, "Testing file write");

if (File.Exists(myFile))
{
  // Access works.
}
else
{
  //Didn't work
}
```

If above code works, then it is most likely that the name you create from `txtProfileLoad.Text` is different from actual file on the drive. On the other hand, if this is a file that doesn't exist yet; then of course it would return false when you check Exists.

Comment: I ran the code but changed the "mytestfile.txt" to txtProfileLoad.Text and entered the filename. File.Exists was able to find the file this time.

Comment: Just modified the code to work in my program, and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string variable and pass the file name to it:

```
string tempFile = txtProfileLoad.Text;
string profile = @"C:\temp\tempfile.txt";
```

Also check out if you could use the file open method instead of `File.Exist`.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx):

> **true** if the caller has the required permissions and path contains the name of an existing file; otherwise, **false**. This method also
>   returns false if path is Nothing, an invalid path, or a zero-length
>   string. If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the
>   specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false
>   regardless of the existence of path.

Have you tried running as an administrator? Try do "right click" on the Visual Studio icon and select "Run as Administrator", and see if you still encounter the same behaviour.

Comment: I have tried running as administrator but it yields similar results.